# What is the best way to convert TBytes (UTF-16) to a string?

Tags: delphi, unicode

What is the best way to convert an array of bytes declared as TBytes to a unicode string in Delphi 2009? In my particular case, the TBytes array has UTF-16 encoded data already (2 bytes for each char).

Since TBytes doesn't store a null terminator, the following will only work if the array happens to have #0 in the memory adjacent to it.

```
MyString := string( myBytes );
```

If not, the string result will have random data at the end (it could also probably cause a read violation depending on how long it took to encounter a #0 in memory).

If I use the ToBytes function, it returns 't'#0'e'#0's'#0't'#0, which is not what I want.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

I ended up using

```
TEncoding.Unicode.GetString( MyByteArray );
```

Answer (score 12):

[StringOf](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/Rio/en/System.SysUtils.StringOf) converts TBytes to a UnicodeString.  [BytesOf](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/Rio/en/System.SysUtils.BytesOf) converts a UnicodeString to TBytes.

Comment: Thanks Bruce, I revised my original question as it wasn't specific enough. The TBytes array is encoded as utf16 data, so ToBytes doesn't work.

Comment: Sweet. As simple as 8 characters: StringOf  :)

Answer (score 4):

If your TBytes contains UTF-16 characters, look at WideStringOf and WideBytesOf.