# Delphi XE2: UTF16LE -> UTF8

Tags: delphi, unicode, utf-8, delphi-xe2, indy

URL : http://www.gagalive.kr/livechat1.swf?chatroom=~~~BBQ

[1]-------------------------------------------------------------------

```
procedure TForm1.FormCreate(Sender: TObject);

begin

 IdTCPClient.Host := '61.97.246.131';

  IdTCPClient.Port := 8080;

  IdTCPClient.Connect;

  IdTCPClient.IOHandler.Write('Ag8m' + Char(0));

  IdTCPClient.IOHandler.Write('LShady|###BBQ' + Char(0));

  IdTCPClient.IOHandler.Write('#' + 'Some Text'  + Char(0));

  IdTCPClient.Disconnect;

end;
```

---

[2]-------------------------------------------------------------------

```
function UTF8FromUTF16_2(sUTF16: UnicodeString): UTF8String; 

begin   

  Result := sUTF16; 

end; 

procedure TForm1.FormCreate(Sender: TObject);

begin

 IdTCPClient.Host := '61.97.246.131';

  IdTCPClient.Port := 8080;

  IdTCPClient.Connect;

  IdTCPClient.IOHandler.Write('Ag8m' + Char(0));

  IdTCPClient.IOHandler.Write('LShady|###BBQ' + Char(0));

  IdTCPClient.IOHandler.Write(UTF8FromUTF16_2('#' + '안녕'  + Char(0)));

  IdTCPClient.Disconnect;

end;
```

---

[1] : working

[2] : not working (string broken > Shady: ??)

See : http://www.gagalive.kr/livechat1.swf?chatroom=~~~BBQ

UTF8FromUTF16 function Original VB Code : [VB 6.0 -> Delphi XE2 Conversion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10561285/vb-6-0-delphi-xe2-conversion)

Help me.. :(

Comment: 2 not working? Use 1. Or describe what you'd expect and what you got.

Comment: 1. char(0)<>ansichar(0)  you will want to attach anischar(0) to a onebyte type 2. is write() really rawbytestring? If it is declared as string it will convert back to UTF16 anyway.

Comment: Yeah, "not working" is pretty hopeless. Which Write overload are you using? The string one? That's going to convert back to UTF-16. Probably need to write bytes directly to retain UTF-8. But I'm guessing because I don't actually know what's wrong.

Comment: GolezTrol // Asia language = 2byte

Comment: IdTCPClient.IOHandler.Write('#' + '안녕'  + Char(0));  < Same String Broken

Comment: Those comments don't help. Be precise and explain it clearly. Don't do it in comments, add some explanation to the question. Also, please format your code properly and remove all the spurious new lines. These things matter.

Comment: Without debugging it's hard to tell, but I would bet that the Korean characters are being corrupted during the concatenation before the UTF8FromUTF16_2 conversion.  Would something like this work better? "Write('#' + UTF8FromUTF16_2('(anyoung)') + char(0)));"  Or will this place the # before the Unicode header for the sting?

Comment: Using `UTF8FromUTF16_2()` is the completely wrong approach to use in this situation.  See my answer.

Answer (score 3):

Strings are UTF-16 encoded in XE2.  #2 does not work because you are passing a `UTF8String` where a `UnicodeString` is expected, so the RTL will perform a UTF-8 -> UTF-16 conversion before Indy sees the data, and then Indy will convert the UTF-16 data to its own default encoding during the transmission.

If you want to transmit a `UnicodeString` as UTF-8, you have to tell Indy to do that, via its `TIdTextEncoding` class, eg:

```
procedure TForm1.FormCreate(Sender: TObject); 
begin 
  IdTCPClient.Host := '61.97.246.131'; 
  IdTCPClient.Port := 8080; 
  IdTCPClient.Connect; 
  IdTCPClient.IOHandler.Write('Ag8m'#0); 
  IdTCPClient.IOHandler.Write('LShady|###BBQ'#0); 
  IdTCPClient.IOHandler.Write('#안녕'#0, TIdTextEncoding.UTF8); // <-- here
  IdTCPClient.Disconnect; 
end;
```

Or:

```
procedure TForm1.FormCreate(Sender: TObject); 
begin 
  IdTCPClient.Host := '61.97.246.131'; 
  IdTCPClient.Port := 8080; 
  IdTCPClient.Connect; 
  IdTCPClient.IOHandler.DefStringEncoding := TIdTextEncoding.UTF8; // <-- here
  IdTCPClient.IOHandler.Write('Ag8m'#0); 
  IdTCPClient.IOHandler.Write('LShady|###BBQ'#0); 
  IdTCPClient.IOHandler.Write('#안녕'#0);
  IdTCPClient.Disconnect; 
end;
```

If you do not tell Indy which encoding to use, it will default to ASCII, which will corrupt/lose your Unicode data.

Comment: Winsock.SendData('#' + Edit1.Text + Char(0)); < TIdTextEncoding.UTF8 how to use in Winsock? –

Comment: You would have to use the `TIdTextEncoding.GetBytes()` method to convert a string to an encoded byte array, then you can send the bytes.

Comment: Thank you but I do not understand the answer.
 I am very sorry.. Can you give a example code..?

Comment: `GetBytes()` returns a `TBytes`, which is a dynamic array of bytes.  Simply pass your desired string to `GetBytes()`, and then pass the byte array to WinSock.  What is hard to understand about that?

Comment: var S : String; B : TBytes; begin B := TEncoding.UTF8.GetBytes('안녕'); Winsock.SendData('#' + B + #0); ///////// It is difficult for me........ Error :(

Comment: You cannot mix strings and bytes like that. If `SendData()` expects a `String` as input, you will have to send the strings and bytes separately: `Winsock.SendData('#'); Winsock.Send(B); Winsock.SendData(#0);`, otherwise you have to encode all of the strings together into a single set of bytes and send it as one call: `B := TEncoding.UTF8.GetBytes('#안녕'#0); Winsock.Send(B);`. How you actually send an array of bytes depends on what methods your Winsock class actually exposes (why you are moving away from `TIdTCPClient`?). I am assuming it has some kind of method for sending raw bytes.

Comment: i don't know receive data in IdTCPClient. IdTCPClient.Socket.ReadLn < Not Working IdTCPClient.IOHandleor < Not Working / Thank you very much. God bless you

Comment: `ReadLn` expects a `LF` terminator by default. Is the server sending a `LF` character? If not, is the server sending any terminator character at all? Your outgoing messages are null-terminated, are the server's inbound messages also null-terminated? `ReadLn()` has an optional `ATerminator` parameter that you can pass `#0` to for reading null-terminated strings.