# How to convert UTF-8 string to PChar in Delphi 2009

Tags: delphi, encoding, utf-8, delphi-2009

I receive a string, which is displayed as `'{'#0'S'#0'a'#0'm'#0'p'#0'l'#0'e'#0'-'#0'M'#0'e'#0's'#0's'#0'a'#0'g'#0'e'#0'}'#0` in the debugger.

I need to print it out in the debug output (`OutputDebugString`).

When I run `OutputDebugString(PChar(mymsg))`, only the first character of the received string is displayed (probably because of the `#0` end-of-string marker).

How can I convert that string into something `OutputDebugString` can work with?

**Update 1:** Here's the code. I want to print the contents of the variable `RxBufStr`.

```
procedure ReceivingThread.OnExecute(AContext : TIdContext);
var
  RxBufStr: String;
begin    
  with AContext.Connection.IOHandler do
  begin
    CheckForDataOnSource(10);
    if not InputBufferIsEmpty then
    begin
      RxBufStr := InputBuffer.Extract();
    end;
  end;
end;
```

Comment: That's UTF16. Show more code. Type of mymsg would help.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan See *Update 1*.

Comment: I found one part of the error. The sending program used a wrong encoding. Now at least part of the message arrives. But there is another problem now - when I send `{Sample-Message-Пробное-сообщение}`, only `{Sample-Message-PQ` appears in the debug output.

Comment: You still have to make sure that the sender and receiver are using the same character encoding for the data.  Indy defaults to ASCII when reading strings.  You can override that by either setting the `IdGlobal.GIdDefaultAnsiEncoding` variable, setting the `IOHandler.DefStringEncoding` property, or passing in a `TIdTextEncoding` to `Extract()` directly.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The data you have shown in the question looks like UTF-16 encoded data rather than UTF-8. However, since you are using a Unicode aware Delphi, and a `string` data type, clearly there has been an encoding mismatch. Your string variable appears to be double UTF-16 encoded if you can see what I mean!

It would appear therefore that `InputBuffer.Extract` is assuming that the data is transmitted using ANSI or UTF-8. In other words, an 8-bit encoding. But in fact the data is transmitted as UTF-16.

To solve the problem you need to align the reading of the buffer with the transmission of the buffer. You need to make sure that both sides use the same encoding. UTF-8 would be a good choice.

If the data in the buffer is UTF-16, then you can extract it with

```
RxBufStr := InputBuffer.Extract(-1, TIdTextEncoding.Unicode);
```

If you switch to UTF-8 then extract it with

```
RxBufStr := InputBuffer.Extract(-1, TIdTextEncoding.UTF8);
```

Comment: Indy does not have `enUTF16`.  It has `enDefault`, `en7Bit`, `en8Bit`, and `enUTF8` (and even then, they are deprecated). For UTF16, you have to use `TIdTextEncoding.Unicode` instead, eg: `RxBufStr := InputBuffer.Extract(-1, TIdTextEncoding.Unicode);`

Comment: @Remy Thanks. Is the answer accurate now?

Comment: I don't know. You should ask @Remy. He's an Indy developer. You could search in the source files of course. And perhaps your Indy is too old to have this type.

Comment: `TIdTextEncoding` is declared in the `IdGlobal.pas` unit. `TIdTextEncoding` was added when Indy started supporting Unicode in Delphi 2009+. `TIdTextEncoding` is available in older compilers too, of course.

Comment: Thanks @Remy. This really should be your answer rather than mine, you being our resident Indy expert!

Comment: @RemyLebeau I added `IdGlobal` to the `uses` clauses, but the compiler complains that the identifier `TIdTextEncoding` can't be found.

Comment: @DmitriPisarenko: if your `IdGlobal` unit does not have `TIdTextEncoding` then you are using an outdated version of Indy and should consider upgrading.  The data you originally showed is not UTF-8 encoded, so `enUTF8` will not solve the problem unless both ends of the connection are using UTF-8.

Comment: I wonder what it is (data in the question).. It's not UTF16 either (should not begin with a NULL).

Comment: @Sertac it doesn't begins with {. It's sort of double UTF-16 encoded.

Comment: @David - It begins with a #0. I understand it is somehow malformed, but I can't quite guess exactly how.

Comment: @Sertac look again, it begins with {

Comment: Oh sorry, I thought it's the debugger putting the braces. Your saying *it doesn't begins with {* didn't help either. <g>

Comment: @sertac yes, I appear to have become illiterate!!

Comment: The string in the question is what you get when you binary copy, e.g. Move, a UTF-16 buffer into an ANSI string.

Answer (score 0):

With

```
RxBufStr := InputBuffer.Extract();
```

the code does not specifiy a terminator or a data size, so it may happen that the client receives only a part of the sent data.

You can read the data with a given (known) length into a TIdBytes array and then convert it to a string using the correct encoding.

One way to do it is

```
TEncoding.Unicode.GetString( MyByteArray );
```

(found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/259973/80901))